# select description from another table sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `A` and `B`. Table `A` has 5 columns (StudentID1,StudentID2,..MatchScore), and Table `B` has 3 columns (StudentID, StudentName,Age).

What I'm trying to do is make a sql statement to Display: StudentName1, StudentName2, MatchScore . Any advice please?

Comment: There is no PL/SQL here so I suggest you remove it from the subject line and tag list. Hover over the tag for a description of what PL/SQL is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` B table twice to get that data like

```
select b1.StudentName as StudentName1,
b2.StudentName as StudentName2
from B b1
join A a on a.StudentID1 = b1.StudentID
join B b2 on a.StudentID2 = b2.StudentID
```